# Factorization system "tilted" by $(L,R)$

Tags: ct.category-theory

Suppose you have a pair of orthogonal factorization systems, $(E_0, M_0), (E_1, M_1)$ in a category $\cal C$ such that $M_0\subseteq M_1$; this [entails](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ternary+factorization+system) that there is a ternary factorization
$$
X\xrightarrow{e_1} A\xrightarrow{e_0 m_1} B\xrightarrow{m_0} Y
$$
where each arrow is labeled according to the class it belongs to.

Suppose now to have *another* OFS $(L,R)$ on $\cal C$, and to factor the middle arrow $A\to B$ into $A\xrightarrow{l} S\xrightarrow{r} B$; this gives a factorization $X\to S\to B$.

> Does this define a third factorization system $(E_{01}\wr L, M_{01}\wr R)$?

Comment: What is the meaning of the tilte symbol. Is it the set of compositions ? Is $E_{01}$ the intersection of $E_0$ and $E_1$ ? Actually it is equal to $E_1$.

Comment: In what application does this arise?

Comment: @PhilippeGaucher $E_{01}$ is not the intersection $E_0\cap E_1$; it is only a shorthand to denote the ternary factorization $\Delta[1]\to FS({\cal C})$ with a single symbol.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

First note that Galois connections are far more common than field theorists would have you believe: *any* binary relation gives rise to one and the two fixed sets a closed under any appropriate algebraic structure.

Write

- $P\perp Q$ for "every member of $P$ is orthogonal (in the sense of factorisation systems) to every member of $Q$";
- $P;Q$ for the set of all composites of members of $P$ followed by members of $Q$;
- $L'=L\cap E_0\cap M_1$ and $R'=R\cap E_0\cap M_1$ (to avoid any ambiguity in this argument); and
- $E=E_1;L'$ and $M=R';M_0$.

Then

- $E_1\perp M_1\supset R'$,
- $E_1\perp M_1\supset M_0$,
- $L'\subset L\perp R\supset R'$ and
- $L'\subset E_0\perp M_0$.

Since orthogonality respects composition, it follows that $E\perp M$, whilst by construction $E;M$ is the entire hom-class of the category.

Therefore $(E,M)$ is a factorisation system.

The things that I have assumed are all proved in [my book](http://paultaylor.eu/prafm) but I don't have a copy to hand to look up the references.

In the question as stated, it is given that $M_0\subset M_1$, but there is no order-relationship between these and $R$. This is why it was necessary to introduce $R'$.  The construction gives a way of handling expressions in the lattice of factorisation systems on a category, so it would be an interesting exercise in lattice theory to find out whether this is modular or even distributive.

Comment: I'm not able to see why you define $L', R'$. I also actually realized that the generality I need is $E_1\subset L\subset E_0$, I think that in this case there are simpler proofs. Anyways, your general argument is neat and elegant. Thanks! If you spend two more words on the definition of $L', R'$ I'll be happy to accept the answer.

Comment: (a rapid check after: I'm convinced by your argument; the same proof of yours seems valid in case $R\subset M_1$ ,using $(L,R)$ instead of $(L', R')$, simply because in that case $r,l\in E_0\cap M_1$)

Comment: Ah, now I see the edit; nice. I think I'll try to do the exercise, do you have an answer for it?

Comment: I am a child indeed (-: